# antonym for 'culture'?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

'Culture' is used to indicate something being normalized. For example: "rape culture"

Is there a word/phrase or anything to describe the opposite of this? Is there a word/phrase that I can put after a word to indicate that it's frowned upon, forbidden, condemned, the opposite of 'culture'?

None of the results from my googling have a punch to them or sound just as good.

The best I can come up with is 'hysteria' - "rape hysteria"

Comment: "Crime"? As in "rape crime". That would appear to be the opposite of "culture", in the sense of "normal and approved practice".

Comment: The opposite of culture? Unacceptable practices, acts or actions.

Comment: @Steve technically correct but not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for words like "hysteria"

Comment: Labeling something an *XYZ culture* doesn’t mean it’s been normalised. It’s just a label for those behaviours etc. You can make value judgments either way about them. E.g.: *XYZ culture* is accepted here but condemned there.

Comment: A cultural *taboo* is something a culture abhors, or claims to be shocked by.

Comment: *Zero tolerance* describes a policy where something isn't tolerated at all, so zero tolerance towards rape would be the opposite of rape culture. There's a British organisation campaigning against rape and violence against women called Zero Tolerance which reflects this usage https://www.zerotolerance.org.uk/

Comment: That's not what _culture_ means, for starts. And not everything has an opposite. If you want an example, figure out how English speakers talk about the great loss of public tobacco smoking Western societies have experienced over the last century. Watch a movie from the 1930s or 40s and there is cigarette smoke everywhere. Big difference. What's it called?

Comment: Something being 'frowned upon, forbidden, condemned' can itself be a part of a culture. It seems that you are being misled by one specific example of the use of this word.

Comment: @jsw29 seems like it but I'm still looking for a word

Comment: The opposite of "rape culture" would be "consent culture." Not everything has an antonym, especially when the would-be opposite is simply nothing, the non-existence of the thing. In this case, though, I agree with what @BhaavyaArora said. If you didn't want to say "consent culture" as the opposite, you'd say "rape taboo" instead (e.g., "The university has a long-established rape culture." vs. "The university has a long-established rape taboo."). One would hope rape being taboo would be the norm, but we're finding out more and more that all too often, it's not.

Comment: The problem with the question is that it is asking for an antonym of a term for a complex concept. When a concept combines several features, one may be able to find the opposite for each of the features, but there isn't going to be a single, definite answer as to what is the opposite of the combination as a whole. What is the antonym for *fast white car*? Is it *slow white car*, or *fast black car* or *slow black car* or *slow black noncar* or . . . ?

Answer (score 2):

Words like "culture" don't have antonyms.

Given that "rape culture" is a culture in which rape is considered normal or acceptable, the opposite would be "anti-rape culture".

Answer (score 0):

Culture is defined on the Wikipedia to include this concept (emphasis added): “Humans acquire culture through the **learning** processes of enculturation and socialization, which is shown by the diversity of cultures across societies.”

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture

An “antonym” to culture could be constructed from the idea of “unlearning”, which could be *forgetting* or *rejection in favor of something else*.  To get something with punch, however, it’s best to look to politics and political messaging.

A *war culture* is opposed by *war resisters*, or more generally by a *war resistance* or *anti-war resistance*.

The problem with this approach is that the resisters end up identifying themselves by the opposite of what they seek to promote. The stronger opponent to a war culture is not an *anti-war movement*, but a *peace movement*.

So although *rape resistance* can use *resistance* to signify a kind of anti-culture, a better expression might be **sexual autonomy**.